# Destructuring Parameters in Chained JS Classes

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototype, super

I want that instances of any of these chained classes are able to pass arguments in a destructuring way (so, I no need to worry about the arguments order). Currently, I'm getting a Type error:

```js
function Participant ({gender, tastes}){
  this.gender = gender;
  this.tastes = tastes || [];
}
function NotPayer({gender, tastes, role}){
  this.role = role || 'kid';
  this.base = Participant;
  this.job = 'Not Valid';
  this.base(gender, tastes);
}
NotPayer.prototype = new Participant;
NotPayer.prototype.constructor = Participant.constructor;

const kid1 = new NotPayer({role: 'nephew', gender: 'male', tastes: ['golf']});
console.log(kid1.gender)
const kid2 = new Participant({ gender: 'male', tastes: ['eat']});
console.log(kid2.gender); // TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'gender' of 'undefined'
```

I tried this:

```js
class Participant {
    constructor({gender, tastes}){
        this.gender = gender;
        this.tastes = tastes || [];
      }
}
class NotPayer extends Participant {
    constructor({gender, tastes, role}){
        super(gender, tastes);
        this.role = role || 'kid';
      }
}
const kid1 = new NotPayer({role: 'nephew', gender: 'male', tastes: ['golf']});
console.log(kid1.gender);//undefined
console.log(kid1.role);//nephew
console.log(kid1.tastes);//[]
const kid2 = new Participant({tastes: ['dance'], gender: 'female2'});
console.log(kid2.gender);// 'female2'
console.log(kid2.tastes);// [ 'dance' ]
```

You notice that there is no error (and the class extending Parent works), but the values passed into the inherited props are missed in the Parent class (`gender` and `role`).

Thanks!

Comment: You missidentified the error. It' actually in this line `NotPayer.prototype = new Participant;` as you don't pass in an object containing the needed properties. Your second version would work if you'd do `super({ gender, tastes} );`

Comment: Ha, It was this line `this.base({gender, tastes});`. Thank you!

Comment: And I replaced the line you noticed with this: `NotPayer.prototype = Participant.prototype;`